# How to delete all lines before and after the specific strings in the file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have played with Powergrep and regular expressions but I don't know how to do that:

I have the text file (source code of webpage) and I want to delete all text (a lot of lines) before the specific string in the code: `STRING1` (html tag) and also all the text after another specific string: `STRING2`. Those strings appears only once in the source code.

Comment: Please be aware, that regular expressions are generally a terrible tool to parse XML/HTML.

Comment: I agree with David Foerster You can use sed , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548864/sed-or-awk-to-print-lines-between-words but I highly advise you run it on a backup first =)

Answer (score 2):

Open a Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and use the one of below one linear command. Don't forget to change the input filename to yours.

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk -v FS="(STRING1|STRING2)" '{print $2}' inputfile > outputfile
```

---

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
grep -Pzo "(?<=STRING1)(.|\n)*(?=STRING2)" inputfile > outputfile
```

or with **DOTALL** (Dot Matches Line Breaks) modifier. It makes `.` to match even `\n`ew line characters.

```
grep -Pzo "(?s)(?<=STRING1).*?(?=STRING2)" inputfile > outpuffile
```

The `(?s)` actives the DOTALL for grep.

or as another alternative to match `\n`ew line chars, simply use:

```
grep -Pzo "(?<=STRING1)[\s\S]*(?=STRING2)" inputfile > outpuffile
```

In [man grep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep.1.html):

```bsh
-o, --only-matching
      Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
      with each such part on a separate output line.

-P, --perl-regexp
      Interpret PATTERN as a Perl compatible regular expression (PCRE)

-z, --null-data
      Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII 
      NUL character) instead of a newline. Like the -Z or --null option, this option 
      can be used with commands like sort -z to process arbitrary file names.
```

`(?<=pattern)`: Known as [Positive Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). A pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark, "less than" symbol, and an equals sign.

So, the `(?<=STRING1).*?` (positive lookbehind) matches the 0 or more occurrences of any characters(which are optional because of using `?` after `.*`) followed by `STRING1` from *inputfile*.

`(?=pattern)`: Known as [Positive Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): The positive lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign.

So, the `.*?(?=STRING2)`: (positive lookahead) matches 0 or more occurrences of any characters followed by `STRING2`.

---

Links for reading more:

<sub>[Advanced Grep Topics](http://caspar.bgsu.edu/~courses/Stats/Labs/Handouts/grepadvanced.htm)  

[GREP for Designers](http://carijansen.com/2013/03/03/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this command:

```
sed -e '/STRING1/,/STRING2/!d' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know where and how to use this command in Powergrep... or where I have to use this command?

Comment: In the terminal.

Comment: This assumes that `STRING1` is the only thing on the line. Try `sed -e '/.*STRING1/,/STRING2.*/!d'` instead.

Comment: @terdon: Do I update my answer with your improvement quoting you or simply expect that the OP read your comment?

Comment: Ideally, you include the info from comments in your answer. Comments can be deleted without warning and are easy to miss. However, my comment was wrong. I mean, you are making that assumption but my solution doesn't change that. Try this instead: `sed -r  's/.*(STRING1)/\1/;s/(STRING2).*/\1/; /STRING1/,/STRING2/!d' file`.

Comment: @terdon: Yes, you have reason, please answer the OP and I'll remove mine.